# Nodemailer does not work and does not give any response

Tags: node.js, email, nodemailer

I'm trying to create a "forgot password" controller, where I send a verification token to the user's email, and for that I created an email sending function through the nodemailer and called it inside the controller "forgotPassword". The problem is that apparently the function is not working, but it also does not return any errors on my console. I would like to know if there is something wrong with this function.

forgotPassword Controller:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const db = require('../../models/index');
const sendEmail = require('../../utils/mailer');

exports.store = async (req, res) => {
    const { email } = req.body;
    const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;

    try {

        const user = await db.User.findOne({ where: { email } });

        if (!user) {
            res.status(400).json('User does not exist.');
        }


        const token = jwt.sign({ id: user.id }, secret, {
            expiresIn: process.env.EXPIRES_FORGOTPASS,
        });

        await user.update({
            tokenReset: token,
        });

        sendEmail({
            from: 'noreply@email.com',
            to: 'admin@gmail.com',
            subject: 'Reset your password',
            text: `Token sending email to reset password account from ${user.email}`,
            html: `<h2>Token sending email to reset password account from ${user.email}</h2>
                    <h4>${token}</h4>
            `,    
        });

        return res.status(200).json('Check the verification link in your email!');
    } catch (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Nodemailer function

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const port = process.env.EMAIL_PORT;

const sendEmail = async ( from, to, subject, text, html ) => {
    try {
        const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: process.env.EMAIL_HOST,
            port: port,
            auth: {
                user: process.env.EMAIL_AUTH_USER,
                pass: process.env.EMAIL_AUTH_PASS,
            }
        });

        await transport.sendMail({
            from: from,
            to: to,
            subject: subject,
            text: text,
            html: html,
        });

        console.log('Email send succesfully');
 
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

module.exports = sendEmail;
```

When testing the application in my postman, it returns the error 500 but it does not return any error in the console, although I put a console.log in my error catch